Characterization of Completely Regular Space
Let be $(X, \mathscr{T})$ a topological space and $\mathscr{D}\subseteq \mathscr{C}_{(X, \mathscr{T})}$.We say that $\mathscr{D}$ is a  basis for $\mathscr{C}_{(X, \mathscr{T})}$ iff $\forall~F\in \mathscr{C}_{(X, \mathscr{T})}$, $\exists~\mathscr{E}\subseteq \mathscr{D}$ not empty such $F=\cap \mathscr{E}$.
I want to show that if the following collection:
$$Z(X)=\{A\subseteq  X\mid \exists~f\in \mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{R}):Z(f):=f^{-1}[\{0\}]=A\}$$
is a basis for $\mathscr{C}_{(X, \mathscr{T})}$, then $(X, \mathscr{T})$ is completely regular. Here $\mathscr{C}_{(X, \mathscr{T})}$ is the colecction of closed sets and $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{R})$ the set of continous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

My attemp:
Let be $F\in \mathscr{C}_{(X, \mathscr{T})}$ and $x\in X\setminus F$. We know there $\exists~\{f_{j}\mid j \in J\}\subseteq \mathscr{C}(X)$ such,
$$F=\bigcap_{j~\in~J}Z(f_{j})$$
where $\{Z(f_{j})\mid j\in J\}\subseteq Z(X)$. Also,
$$X\setminus F=\bigcup_{j~\in~J}X\setminus Z(f_{i})=\bigcup_{j~\in~J}X\setminus f^{-1}_{j}[\{0\}]$$
$$=\bigcup_{j~\in~J}f^{-1}_{j}[ \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}]$$
So I know there is some $i\in J$ such $f_{i}(x)=0$. Define $f(x)=1-(f_{i}(x))^{-1}x$ wich seem continous, then $f(x)=0$ and $f[X\setminus F]\subseteq \{1\}$. But, how to see that codomain of $f$ is just $[0,1]$ and not all $\mathbb{R}$?

The final paragraph of your proof attempt is quite confusing. What you get from your previous reasoning is that, there exists $i \in J$ s.t. $f_i(F) \subseteq \{0\}$ and $f_i(x) \neq 0$. Now you can just choose,
$$f = \min\left\{1, \left|\frac{f_i}{f_i(x)}\right|\right\}$$
Then $f$ is continuous, has range in $[0, 1]$, $f(F) \subset \{0\}$, and $f(x) = 1$, which seems to be what you want.
